# Producer-Consumer example, both in lock(this) block

Tags: c#, multithreading

I was looking at Example 2 on this [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645740%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) page about Thread synchronization with Monitor.Pulse().

A Cell object is created and passed to both the producer and the consumer objects.

```
Cell cell = new Cell( );
CellProd prod = new CellProd(cell, 20);
CellCons cons = new CellCons(cell, 20);
```

A thread is created for each of those two

```
Thread producer = new Thread(new ThreadStart(prod.ThreadRun));
Thread consumer = new Thread(new ThreadStart(cons.ThreadRun));
```

The ThreadRun in each case being a loop that calls Cell.ReadFromCell() or Cell.WriteToCell() depending on consumer/producer. For example, the producer does this

```
public void ThreadRun( )
{
  for(int looper=1; looper<=quantity; looper++)
     cell.WriteToCell(looper);  // "producing"
}
```

The bit I don't understand is that in each of these methods they start with a

```
lock(this)
```

And since it was the same Cell object (ie, the 'this' in the above lock statement) passed to both, I would have thought that only one thread could be in this section of code at a time. Yet from Monitor.Pulse() and Monitor.Wait() code that follows it looks like both threads are in those sections at the same time. If one had the lock and hit a Monitor.Wait() then the other thread could never Pulse because it is blocked waiting for the lock.

I'm guessing there is a simple solution and I have misunderstood something, from my tests with running the code it looks like both threads are in their critical sections at the same time, so the lock(this) isn't doing what I was under the impression it should do.

Comment: Note that it is a poor programming practice to `lock(this)`. Instead, create a private field of type object and lock on that. The reason it is a poor practice is because *anyone* could take out a lock on that object; if your lock ordering guarantees depend on only code *inside* the type being able to lock then locking on this makes the code fragile and hard to analyze. Locking on a private means that you know that *only* code that could get a reference to the private object can take out the lock.

Comment: Eric, I completely agree but MSDN should not provide such sample code in the first place. Most of the time, people use 'lock(this)' statement because they think that if it's on MSDN, it must be the right way to do this. Is there a way to submit request to update MSDN content?

Comment: @SolutionYogi: Good point. I will bring it to the attention of the doc manager. Thanks!

Comment: @SolutionYogi: The doc manager points out to me that the page in question is from 2003. The updated page uses the better practice of declaring a private object: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx. Unfortunately, a lot of the time errors remain on older pages because it is extremely expensive to spend a lot of time scouring several millions of pages of decade-old documentation looking for bugs.

Comment: @EricLippert, I completely understand that it's practically impossible to update each and every document. And that is why I was wondering if there is any way I can log a request (like how we do for bugs with Connect) to get the documentation updated. Thank you for looking into this.

Comment: On a related note, It's great that MSDN has 'Community Content' right below official docs. Though I wonder why there hasn't been much participation from the community. Compare this to php's documentation. E.g. http://www.php.net/fwrite Two things jump out: You can go do documentation of any function directly by typing the URL. Second, there are tons of useful comments for each function (I think it could be because one doesn't have to use/create another login to add a note.

Comment: Is anybody at MS thinking about ways to improve community participation? One can also add 'voting' so that good comments rises to top. Documentation can even point to highly relevant questions on SO.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The thing you're missing is that `Monitor.Wait(this)` will *release* the lock on `this` until it's woken up. So yes, your consumer thread *looks* like it's in the lock and therefore owns it, but really it's temporarily released it.

From [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ateab679.aspx):

> When a thread calls Wait, it releases the lock on the object and enters the object's waiting queue. The next thread in the object's ready queue (if there is one) acquires the lock and has exclusive use of the object. All threads that call Wait remain in the waiting queue until they receive a signal from Pulse or PulseAll, sent by the owner of the lock. If Pulse is sent, only the thread at the head of the waiting queue is affected. If PulseAll is sent, all threads that are waiting for the object are affected. When the signal is received, one or more threads leave the waiting queue and enter the ready queue. A thread in the ready queue is permitted to reacquire the lock.